# Is it possible to get rid of auto-formatting of margins around a textbox?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to move the smaller text that appears at the bottom closer to the top, larger textbox. The problem is when I try to move it close enough, pink lines appear, the next margin increment jumps from 0.00 to 0.11 (no in-between margins), instead of in 0.014 increments (0.00 to 0.014, 0.014 to 0.028, etc.) Photoshop usually allows.

Is there anyway to get rid of the autoformatting that occurs here, so that I could put the smaller textbox in a margin somewhere in between the first picture and the second picture (margin value between 0.00 to 0.11)?

[image]

[image]

Margin from first picture and second picture is the smallest increment possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Adobe's new fangled Snapping.

You can turn this off here, as the unhighlighted Snap that's ticked (all of it's behaviour) or just underneath you can turn off some parts of its behaviours, as per the highlighted flyout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also if you want to keep snapping turned on but want to turn it off one time, press ctrl + drag the item you wish to move, and it will move the selected layer in the smallest increment possible.